# Jquery: only loads the next page on first click of "load more..."

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to load contents on each click of the text "load more" at the end if the DIV. The code I have currently is as below:

```
<div id="Container"> <p class="load">load more</P> </div>
```

and

```
$(".load:last").click(function(){
$(".load:last").load("nextPage.php", function() {
$(this).hide();

$("div#Container").append($(this).html());
$("div#Container").append("<p class=\"load\">load more...</p>");

});
```

The first click works as it loads more from nextPage.php. However the consequent click doesn't trigger the load. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You dont need $(".load:last") as you are hiding the previous load more para just make it $(".load").click(function(){...});

Comment: I did try that but was with the same result. I've also tried with :last and no hide(), as well as no :last and using "load" as an id instead of a class, but it didn't make any difference either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(".load:last").live('click', function () {
        $(this).remove();
        //Or
        // $(this).hide();
        $(".load:last").load("nextPage.php", function () {
            $("div#Container").append($(this).html());
            $("div#Container").append("<p class=\"load\">load more...</p>");
        });
    });
```

Comment: live is deprecated in favor of on since jQuery 1.7, if you are using 1.4+, use delegate instead, from the docs: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

Comment: This works for me, thanks to both of you! Double checked my jQuery and turns out I was using 1.6 jQuery, therefore .on() didn't trigger but .live worked.

Answer (score 0):

As the `.load` append every time to the `div#Container` as new, you should use a live event handler to that `.load` like following:

```
$("div#Container").on('click', '.load', function() {
  $(this).parent('div#Container').load('nextPage.php', function() {
     $('div#Container').append("<p class=\"load\">load more...</p>");
  })
})
```

Comment: It doesn't trigger any load for some reason. I also tried with alert("hello") within the on() event handler instead, but it was never triggered when "load more" is clicked

Comment: Sorry it did trigger the event -- it wasn't working because I'm using 1.6 jQuery so had to use .live(). The event handler doesn't do exactly what I was looking for but it helped me to find the resolution nevertheless, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using **.live() method or.on() of jquery**, this attaches an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

[Click here for information and example for .live event in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
I hope this will definitely solve you problem.

Best of Luck! :)

Comment: live is deprecated in favor of on since jQuery 1.7, if you are using 1.4+, use delegate instead, from the docs: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

Comment: thanks to put light on this topic... yes .live() method is depreccated. .on() is in use